# How to enable internet traffic logging in OpenVpn?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, logging

I am currently running a VPN server for my school without any data logging.

However, despite many warnings not to do illegal stuff, I have now received a DMCA notice for torrenting and I think that I need to start logging some internet data to find out who is behind this.

I am still quite new to OpenVpn and its works, so I was wondering if anyone knew how to do this?

Ideally this would be some basic information as to which users connected to which sites/downloaded files.

Server is running Debian 8.5 64 bit. If it helps, the server was set up using this installation script:

https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install

Incase it helps, server.conf:

```
port 443
proto tcp
dev tun
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
cel-verify crl.pem
duplicate-cn
status openvpn-status.log
management localhost 25566
log-append openvpn.log
verb 2
```

Comment: Care to tell us more about the setup - eg what OS is the OpenVPN server running on, what resources is it providing, what interfaces does it have, how are IP addresses assigned, is NAT involved, and if so, where ?

Comment: OpenVPN only logs the amount of data each client transfers but no other details, so you will need a traffic analyser of some sort to monitor your network.  I presume your school is not a technology school.